# Java 8 stream foreach vs map

Tags: arraylist, foreach, java-8, stream

In my application I was trying to add elements of a list into another list if another list  doesn't contain those elements.

I was trying it to do it like this:

```
 List<String> list1 = dto.getList1() != null ? couponDto.getLis1(): new ArrayList<>();
 list1.stream().filter(item -> !secondList.contains(item)).map(secondList::add);
```

I didn't get any error while using it like above but item were not added to secondList. After speding too much time I was able to fix it like below:

```
List<String> list1 = dto.getList1() != null ? couponDto.getLis1(): new ArrayList<>();
list1.stream().filter(item -> !secondList.contains(item)).forEachOrdered(secondList::add);
```

I understand map is used to map to one value to another so isn't it what I was doing by adding the items to list.

Could anybody help me to understand this ?

Thanks

Comment: Streams don't execute until a terminal operation is called, and `map` is an intermediate operation.

Comment: Also, should point out that the `Function` passed to `map` should be [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) and [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness).

Comment: Why not use a `Set` then?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have streamed data you need to call terminal functions (e.g: `forEach`, `collect`) to complete the operation. In your code, `forEachOrdered` is a terminal operation but `map` isn't, so it worked.

Comment: But then why map didn't give any error if there was no terminal function to complete the operation.

Comment: @Manish Because ["terminal" versus "intermediate" operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) on streams is an API-level distinction. The compiler has no idea what that means, nor does it care. And the Stream API can't offer any help, because how would it know you don't intend to invoke a terminal operation some time later? Essentially, what you did was _build_ a stream but then never _executed_ it. That's valid code, even if it doesn't do what you meant it to do.